# Creating a musical QWERTY keyboard. Plays error sound instead of sound

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

Making a QWERTY musical keyboard for school. This code isn't working. The bit where it's supposed to play a noise (20th Century Fanfare) It plays a windows noise instead... Any ideas?

```
def playSound02(canvas, synchronous):

async = winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC
canvas.data["soundCounter"] += 1
sound02 = ["centuryfox.wav" ]
sound02 = sound02[canvas.data["soundCounter"] % len(sound02)]
winsound.PlaySound(sound02, async)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can only use .wav files and they have to be in the same folder as the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the Windows API documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx)

PlaySound searches the following directories for sound files: the current directory; the Windows directory; the Windows system directory; directories listed in the PATH environment variable; and the list of directories mapped in a network. If the function cannot find the specified sound and the SND_NODEFAULT flag is not specified, PlaySound uses the **default system event sound instead**. If the function can find neither the system default entry nor the default sound, it makes no sound and returns FALSE.